# SparseArray output triggers "unsafe dynamic content" warning

Tags: output-formatting, sparse-arrays, raspberry-pi, elided-forms

The first basic example in the documentation of `SparseArray`:

```
s = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}]
```

when executed and saved in a notebook triggers the following warning when that notebook is reopened:  "This file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content."  Apparently this is true of every notebook that contains a (computed) sparse array.

Is there a reason for keeping users of sparse arrays in a high state of alert?

**Edited to Add:**  A screenshot for the skeptics:

[image]

**Edited to Add 2:**  This document was saved to "/Users/grant/Desktop".  Saving a copy to "/Users/grant/Documents" produced a document without the warning.  Apparently desktops are unsafe.

Comment: The warning is not down to that code. You must have other material in the notebook that uses `Dynamic`

Comment: I open a new notebook, paste the line above in, execute it to get an "Out[1]", save the notebook, quit Mathematica, restart Mathematica, open the notebook, and there it is.

Comment: Mathematica v. 10.0.2.0; OS X v. 10.9.5.

Comment: explanation and solution below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In version 10 Wolfram introduced some dynamic panels in output objects. These are intended to provide some useful brief information (I guess) about what is stored.

[image]

Because these panels are dynamic they trigger an unsafe dynamic content warning if the notebook is not in a trusted path. I prefer to switch this dynamic panelling off, which you can do by setting this system option:

```
SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> "IconicElidedForms" -> False]
```

When you do that the dynamic panel no longer appears in the output and consequently you do not get any unsafe dynamic content warnings.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `SetSystemOptions`.  These dyanmic panels are a nightmare on the Raspberry Pi version.  If no one objects, I think it is worthwhile to include the RPi tag for future visitors trying to optimize the FE on that system.